# Do spoiler tags work in tables?

Tags: support, spoilers, markdown, formatting

Let's find out...

| My header |
| --- |
| Some public info |
| >! Some secret info |

Based on the preview, it looks like spoiler tags *don't* work in tables.

So are there any options for hiding a spoiler in a table?

(I was trying to reformat [a comparison answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117340/58193) into a table, but the spoiler tags are tripping me up.)

Comment: See [Spoilers don't support block formatting (and so don't format well) - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116613/spoilers-dont-support-block-formatting-and-so-dont-format-well).

Answer (score 5):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), see [the main meta post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357165/345161):

> Yep, this is definitely by design. Block-level elements like blockquotes, code blocks or spoilers won't work in Markdown tables. – Ham Vocke♦

You could probably come up with some weird and funky workaround to still include spoilers in the table but it would most likely have more cons than pros for it.

Really for this particular case you're going to need to ask yourself:

- does the answer really need to be moved to table markdown?
- and do the spoilers really need to stay hidden behind the spoiler markdown?

Personally I'm not sure it really needs to move to table markdown in the first place so you might just be better leaving that answer as is for now.

Comment: I was trying to read the answer and found it quite onerous having to scroll up and down the page to compare point by point.  Perhaps you could take a look now and see [how it compares](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117340/1498).  I ended up just getting rid of the spoilers, on the assumption that if somebody wants a point-by-point comparison of the book and movie, they're probably well past the point of caring about spoilers in one or the other.

Comment: @Kyralessa I was somewhat worried the text in the table might end up too small. It certainly looks smaller than normal body text but not too bad.